# Finding calculated values in Excel

Tags: excel

I am working on an inherited spread-sheet, which includes a pivot table with a database table as its source. One of the columns is similar to another column, except that it has additional labels, which are sums of other labels. E.g a total column which is price + VAT. 
It is NOT a calculated item, and the column is not in the original database table. 
Where does this column come from, and how can I view and edit the formulae that make up the additional labels ?

Answer (score 0):

The summation was actually brought about by a grouping, which had the effect of creating a new field, in which the original creator assigned aliases for the grouped items.